# How to delete all rows in BigTable GCP using nodejs without prefix

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to delete all rows without a prefix from bigtable using node js but it keeps on throwing error saying **Error: A prefix is required for deleteRows**...

Tried this

```
table.deleteRows(function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      // All rows were deleted successfully.
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing in an empty prefix which would match everything like so:

```
table
  .deleteRows('')
  .then(result => {
    const apiResponse = result[0];
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Handle the error.
  });
```

There is an example in the reference docs, prefix seems required
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigtable/latest/Table.html#deleteRows

Comment: Thank you. But this did not work. Still it is not deleting all rows..
I read this in below doc but it is not working too.
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigtable/blob/master/src/index.ts
` 
 If you omit the prefix, you can delete all rows in your table.
 
  table.deleteRows(function(err) {
   if (!err) {
     //All rows were deleted successfully.
   }
 });